# AVR Assembly why does LDI instruction can only use R16 - R31 registers

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, avr

Hello I came across this exam question in a past paper and I am baffled, so far no research has given me a conclusive answer as most people just say its a limitation of the processor. I am very sure we did not cover this in class.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: There is no other answer. They decided to allow full 8 bit immediate and with a 4 bit opcode that leaves 4 bits for the register operand which means only 16 can be addressed. The designers chose the R16-31.

Comment: not only LDI but also other instructions that operate on an 8-bit immediate. There's nothing better you can do with only 16 bits. 4 bits for the opcode, 4 for the register field and the remaining 8 bits for the immediate[

Comment: @Jester I presume that what you wrote (even w/out the last sentence) would qualify as a correct answer for that exam. And it's way different from just "its a limitation of the processor" answer)) Things that are obvious to engineers may not be as obvious to students.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the design of hardware and its attendant instruction set.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that `LDI` is just supported for the upper 16 registers.

When you have a look at the ISA (instruction set architecture) you'll notice that the same applies to `SUBI`, `SBCI`, `ANDI`, `ORI` and `CPI`, each of which needs 12 bits in the opcode table: 8 bits for the 8-bit immediate and 4 bits to encode which of R16... R31 is the destination. This means that just to provide these 6 instructions with immediate, you are already occupying 37.5% of opcodes.

Supporting R0... R31 would require 75% of opcode just for 6 instructions: All AVR opcodes are 16-bit opcodes (except `LDS`, `STS`, `CALL`, `JMP` which are 32 bit), and you can only encode so much instructions with 16 bits

Take for example the following 2-reg instructions: `ADD`, `ADC`, `SUB`, `SBC`, `CP`, `CPC`, `AND`, `OR`, `EOR`, `LSR`, `ASR`, `ROR`, `MOV`. Each of these 13 instructions occupies 2^(5+5) opcodes because each one has to encode one of 2^5 possible source resp destination registers, summing up to more than 20% of opcode space. And we did not yet consider jumps (`RJMP`, `RCALL`, branches) or memory accesses like `LDD`, `STD`, `IN`, `OUT`.

Terminology: "opcode" above means all the bits needed to encode one specific machine instruction.

Comment: terminology: the *opcode* is the part of the instruction that determines *which* instruction it is, separate from the operands.  We already have a name for the whole instruction, and that's "instruction".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode.  Using the term "opcode" to mean the whole encoding is sometimes done, but it's confusing when you want to distinguish which bits mean what in an instruction encoding.